# Using R Quarto With Mermaid and FontAwesome Does Not Render Icons

Tags: r-markdown, quarto, mermaid

I am trying to include FontAwesome icons in R Quarto. I am rendering to a presentation in PPTX. However, it does not matter which presentation final type I select or any other output type.
Sample code to replicate issue:

````
```{mermaid}
flowchart TD
    B["fab:fa-twitter for peace"]
    B-->C[fa:fa-ban forbidden]
    B-->D(fa:fa-spinner)
    B-->E(A fa:fa-camera-retro perhaps?)
```
````

The nodes render but none of the `fa:*` items are showing. I see the class is created in the HTML (if rendered to Reveal.JS or HTML):

```
<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
```

How can I get R Quarto (or other R markdown) using mermaid to include the font awesome icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [fontawesome extension](https://github.com/quarto-ext/fontawesome) which works at least for HTML outputs. I assume that by initializing in the text instead of only using the mermaid environment, it has the necessary HTML font awesome dependency to render the icons correctly.

````
---
format: html
---

Initialize {{< fa thumbs-up >}} and then it should work:

```{mermaid}
flowchart TD
    B["fab:fa-twitter for peace"]
    B-->C[fa:fa-ban forbidden]
    B-->D(fa:fa-spinner)
    B-->E(A fa:fa-camera-retro perhaps?)
```
````

[image]

Comment: A little rough around the edges to have to init first with FA in a text chunk but it does now work.